# Natural language processing parse tree abbreviations

Tags: c#, .net, nlp, wordnet

I've been working on a project that I have to learn to use NLP tools for. I'm writing it in C#, and am thus using the SharpNLP library (based off of OpenNLP), which also includes a WordNet access library. I'm doing some practice with the chunking feature because my program is going to use that a lot to modify some words in a sentence but not others, depending on the role they play in the sentence.

The chunker outputs phrases with parse-tree abbreviation tags attached to them, as well as attached to the individual words (which is more important to me for my situation), but the problem is that I don't know what half of them mean, and I can't seem to find a full list of what all the abbreviations mean; all the parse tree tutorials I find just list the ones that exist on that parse tree. I know things like NP = Noun Phrase, PP = Preposition Phrase, VP = Verb Phrase, and I think that DT = Determiner (I saw it abbreviated as D once). There's a couple more that I know, but I'm sure there's a lot that I don't know (JJ, NNS, NN, etc) so I'm wondering if there is a list somewhere that has all of them listed, as well as ideally a description/examples of each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Microsoft Cognitive Services](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/linguistic-analysis-api/documentation/POS-tagging) uses the [Penn Tree Bank specification](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/) which I would assume is pretty close, if not the same.

Comment: The links on that website are mostly broken, but I searched for "Treebank part of speech tags" and found [this page](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html) which has exactly what I need. Turns out my library's chunker is based off of Treebank, so the page I found matches what my chunker will output perfectly. Thanks!